# jquery dynatree class methods

Tags: jquery, dynatree

I'm a new user of dynatree plugin. When I read the documentation, I found the list of tree and node class member functions, such as tree.getRoot(), node.countChildren(). However, when I tried to use them, it complained that no such methods were found.
Here is a sample code I am testing with:

```
var tree = ("#test").dynatree(treeData);
var rootNode = tree.getRoot(); //not working
var rootNode2 = ("#test").dynatree("getRoot"); //this works
var numChildren = rootNode2.countChildren(); //not working
```

Help please. Thanks.
-JJ

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the leading `$`?

Valid samples are:

```
var rootNode = $("#tree").dynatree("getRoot");
var tree = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree");
var node = $("#tree").dynatree("getActiveNode");
node.setTitle(node.data.title + ", " + new Date());
```

See here for samples (click `View source code`):
  http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-api.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var tree = $("#test").dynatree(treeData);
```

Your first line gives you the #test html element.

In order to obtain the tree object try:

```
var tree = $("#test").dynatree(treeData).dynatree("getTree");
```

Now these lines will work:

```
var rootNode = tree.getRoot();
var numChildren = rootNode.countChildren();
```